# Error when trying to update the primary key value

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to update all values of a record including the primary key value which is `user_name` so what I did is that I created a variable `@username1` that holds the current username (so that I can use it in the where clause) and `@username` holds the new value of the username that I want to update it to.

However every time I execute the procedure, I get error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__Users__7C9273C5C682108D'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Users'

```
alter proc updateinfo 
@username1 varchar(20),
@username varchar(20),
@password varchar(15) , 
@personal_email varchar(50), 
@experience int , 
@date_of_birth datetime , 
@first_name varchar(20),
@middle_name varchar(20) , 
@last_name varchar(20)
as 
begin 
  update Users
    set user_name=@username, password=@password, personal_email=@personal_email,
        experience=@experience, date_of_birth=@date_of_birth,
        first_name = @first_name, middle_name=@middle_name, last_name=@last_name
    where EXISTS (select user_name from users where user_name=@username1) 
end
```

Comment: A primary key **MUST** be an unique value, so it can't exist twice. May also consider using numeric values as primary key.

Comment: Primary keys are not updatable. You can only refer to it to update data. So you should update the other attributes but not the primary key.

Comment: @chade_ well in case of this database i was required to set the username (varchar) as the primarykey . However i dont know how am i supposed to update the username to a new value . i just want to set the old username with a new username

Comment: @cdaiga then why do we usually add statemnts "on update cascade or on update set null" if they are unupdatable

Comment: @marwagaser find a better explanation [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44956/good-explanation-of-cascade-on-delete-update-behavior)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your query effectively tries to update all rows of the table:

```
update Users
...
where EXISTS (select user_name from users where user_name=@username1)
```

This means that whenever there's a row in `users` where `user_name` equals your input `@username1`, *all* rows of `users` will be updated - because that `EXISTS` condition will be true regardless of which row is considered for update. Luckily for you, such update will fail because it will try to set multiple `user_name`s to the same value.

What you probably wanted to do is:

```
update Users
set user_name=@username, password=@password, personal_email=@personal_email,
    experience=@experience, date_of_birth=@date_of_birth, first_name = @first_name,
    middle_name=@middle_name, last_name=@last_name
where user_name=@username1
```